# Getting query results without specific class

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there a way to get query results back without making a class specific to the returnable data.

I got this

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
[WebMethod]
public string GetLocation()
{
    var json = "";
    var location = from result in dc.Auto_Kada_SIA_Locations
                   select result;

    json = jss.Serialize(location);

    return json;
}
```

It works fine using DataClasses generating for specific Tables i choose, but what is the best aproach to executing a query(with data from multiple tables) and serializing it to json?

Comment: Select into anonymous type.

Comment: For example using dc.ExecuteQuery() or something similar with a custom sql query - what type should i pass the or it would not work like that?

Comment: It is always advisable to have a separate class (View Model) for the data that is returned.

Comment: Can i generate a class for the query in the .dbml file?